# Is it possible to send user new password after they clicking on forgot password in word press

Tags: plugins, activation, password, reset

In word press is it possible to send users to new password after they are clicking on forgot password page ?

Actually I dont want to send any url to users email which can take them to any page.

Also if it is possible that I send them to only key (without link) and after clicking on forgot password user redirect to that page where they enter the key which received on their email earlier after clicking on forgot password button.

Regards

Comment: WordPress doesn't send the actual password because sending passwords over email is very unsafe. Why don't you want to send a link?

Comment: Hi ! Jacob, Thanks a lot for your answer but I make a web view based android app and I don't want that normal users even know my site's url. So, In registration I put the activation key and it's works great. But in lost password it's not work or I don't have any idea. Sorry ! I am talking about hiding url for normal users not advanced users. I know very well that advanced user know anyhow my site's url. But it's just for those normal peoples only. So, My friend please help me for that.Or suggest me something that I can try using my limited knowledge of coding.

Answer (score -2):

Sending password or as you said key in email is not the safe way. WordPress send a link in email when click on forgot password button. 
When you click that link it redirects to a default WordPress page for reset password there you have enter and that's it and this is the easiest way for the user.

Like you said you want to send a key in email it's like OTP and user need to enter while login and again before expiration of that key user have to change their password so it's double work for them. If you want to do it then you have to make your own custom code/plugin to perform this action in safe way and your website must have proper instructions for the users.

---

Hey,
I did some research. I found following plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/

You have to install this plugin goto pie register-> Notification -> Select tab User notification-> select template from dropdown 
"Password reset request".

When you select this template it will give you to edit forgot password email in editor, where you can remove (%reset password url%) from there.
So in forgot password email url won't come instead you can put your key but for dynamic key genration have to see further.

Hope this helps!
Prasad :)

Comment: Hi ! Prasad, Thanks a lot for your answer but I make a web view based android app and I don't want that normal users even know my site's url. So, In registration I put the activation key and it's works great. But in lost password it's not work or I don't have any idea. Sorry ! I am talking about hiding url for normal users not advanced users. I know very well that advanced user know anyhow my site's url. But it's just for those normal peoples only. Hey please help me for that. I have no knowledge of coding. Or suggest me something that I can try using my limited knowledge of coding.

Comment: I refine my answer. You can check if this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: HI ! Prasad, Thanks for suggesting Pie. But Did you know about some of site has that facility where user make forgot password request and site send automatically generate new password on mail. Instead of my above if it is possible suggest me how can I do the same or else you have any other.